# Javascript Ball Class? - EDIT

Tags: javascript, html, c++, function, class

I have been trying to play around with the idea of a Ball class within Javascript that is within an HTML file. Check out my code to see what my hang up is. I have seen people use both a `function` and a `class` to accomplish this but I can't seem to get this to work. I feel like I am doing more of a C++ style rather than Javascript. Any suggestions?

```
    class Ball {
            constructor(x, y, radius, dx, dy) {
                this.x      = x;
                this.y      = y;
                this.radius = radius;
                this.dx     = dx;
                this.dy     = dy;
                }

            get X() {
                return this.x;
                }

            get Y() {
                return this.y;
                }

            get Radius() {
                return this.radius;
                }

            get Dx() {
                return this.dx;
                }

            get Dy() {
                return this.dy;
                }

            drawBall() {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(get X(), get Y(), get Radius(), 0, Math.PI*2);
                ctx.fillStyle() = "black";
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
                }

        };

    var Ball1 = new Ball(canvas.width/2, canvas.height-30, 10, 2, -2);

        function drawBall() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(get X(), get Y(), get Radius(), 0, Math.PI*2);
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawBall();
        drawBall2();

        if((Ball1.get X() + Ball1.get Dx()) > canvas.width-Ball1.get Radius() || (Ball1.get X() + Ball1.get Dx()) < Ball1.get Radius()) {
            Ball1.set Dx(-(Ball1.get Dx()));
        }
        if(Ball1.get Y() + Ball1.get Dy() > canvas.height-Ball1.get Radius() || y + dy < ballRadius) {
            dy = -dy;
        }
        if(x2 + dx2 > canvas.width-ballRadius || x2 + dx2 < ballRadius) {
            dx2 = -dx2;
        }
        if(y2 + dy2 > canvas.height-ballRadius || y2 + dy2 < ballRadius) {
            dy2 = -dy2;
        }

        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        x2 += dx2;
        y2 += dy2;

    }
```

I know there are discrepancies in my code like things not matching but I don't think I am on the right track. Thanks ahead of time!

**EDIT!**
Here is the code that I started with that works so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Game</title>
    <style>
        * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="580"></canvas>

<script>
    //Javascript goes here 

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var ballRadius = 10;
    //ball 1
    var x = canvas.width/2;
    var y = canvas.height-30;
    var dx = 2;
    var dy = -2;
    //ball 2
    var x2 = canvas.width/3;
    var y2 = canvas.height-30;
    var dy2 = -4;
    var dx2 = 4;

    function drawBall() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }


    function drawBall2() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x2, y2, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawBall();
        drawBall2();

        if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
            dx = -dx;
        }
        if(y + dy > canvas.width-ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
            dy = -dy;
        }
        if(x2 + dx2 > canvas.width-ballRadius || x2 + dx2 < ballRadius) {
            dx2 = -dx2;
        }
        if(y2 + dy2 > canvas.height-ballRadius || y2 + dy2 < ballRadius) {
            dy2 = -dy2;
        }

        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        x2 += dx2;
        y2 += dy2;

    }

setInterval(draw, 10);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing.If you define properties like get Dx(). You must call them like properties. Ball1.Dx. Where is ctx coming from? It looks you have problems using es6 javascript. http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html

Comment: The `ctx` comes from the code here:
`var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");`

Comment: @Tylersong55 what happens when you run your code? What errors do you get? Or does it just "feel like it's not going to work"?

Comment: Nothing happens besides a blank screen with a canvas. I had it running with two balls before where they would bounce off of the borders but since putting in the class declaration it doesn't work. The variables were individually made instead of being in the class on the first run. And does all the script for the class go in the body of an html or in the head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code a little bit just to give you an Idea. This is still not a very good code design. The example will only work in modern Browsers because you use es6 features like class. I think you should start with some javascript fundamentals first.

```js
"use strict";

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y, radius, dx, dy) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
  }

  get X() {
    return this.x;
  }

  get Y() {
    return this.y;
  }

  get Radius() {
    return this.radius;
  }

  get Dx() {
    return this.dx;
  }

  get Dy() {
    return this.dy;
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, this.Radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var Ball1 = new Ball(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - 30, 10, 2, -2);
Ball1.draw(ctx);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Simple Javascript

```js
  var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  function drawBall(ctx, x, y, r) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
  }


  drawBall(ctx, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - 30, 10, 2, -2);
```

Comment: I tried running that code in my browser and nothing changed. What should I be doing to go about doing this? Should it not be a class? Is there a template you can show me that will give me an idea on how to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: What browser you are using? I used chrome. As I said this will only run in modern Browser that supports Javascript classes

Comment: I am using Chrome at the moment. Is there something better to use?

Comment: I changed the code a little bit to make it fit your code. If you copy and paste this in your script tags it should work.

Comment: Also note that it is perfectly viable to use ES6 code, feel free to use classes and any of the new syntax, but ensure you use a transpiler to support older browsers...look at webpack for deploying your projects